# spawn-fcgi -F other child processes not being used

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I am running a Fastcgi app written in c++ with Nginx and it is working pretty well. The app starts via spawn-fcgi with 4 child processes using the following command:

```
spawn-fcgi -f ./fcgiapp -p 9000 -F 4
```

HOWEVER.... I noticed that only one process is used for everything.

I've run a load test with JMeter and only one process gets all the load.

I'm using Nginx as web server and using the fastcgi_pass to localhost:9000 and everything works fine.

Does anyone know what has to be done to have all processes processing the load passed by Nginx?